# Can Tensorflow Federated be installed on Apple Silicon M1?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow, pip, tensorflow-federated

I want install Tensorflow Federated in a macOS with Apple Silicon M1.

I have tried installing Python 3.9.1 with pyenv and create a virtual environment. Then I installed the package.

```sh
pip install tensorflow-federated
```

Some errors raised because of dependency conflict when installed Tensorflow Federated. You can see partial of error logs below:

```
...

    clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
    clang: error: the clang compiler does not support 'faltivec', please use -maltivec and include altivec.h explicitly
    error: Command "clang -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include -I/opt/homebrew/opt/readline/include -DNPY_INTERNAL_BUILD=1 -DHAVE_NPY_CONFIG_H=1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE=1 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -DNO_ATLAS_INFO=3 -DHAVE_CBLAS -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/umath -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/include -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/include/numpy -Inumpy/core/src/common -Inumpy/core/src -Inumpy/core -Inumpy/core/src/npymath -Inumpy/core/src/multiarray -Inumpy/core/src/umath -Inumpy/core/src/npysort -I/Users/user/projects/ucloud/federated/venv/include -I/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/include/python3.9 -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/common -Ibuild/src.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/npymath -c numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.c -o build/temp.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.o -MMD -MF build/temp.macosx-11.2-arm64-3.9/numpy/core/src/multiarray/array_assign_scalar.o.d -faltivec -I/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers" failed with exit status 1
    ----------------------------------------
    ERROR: Failed building wheel for numpy
  Failed to build numpy
  ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/15/fb/86d26128a5ea42d20f402109e76a63e59845d73171887a08a43a28b847dc/h5py-3.0.0.tar.gz#sha256=7d3803be1b530c68c2955faba726dc0f591079b68941a0c0269b5384a42ab519 (from https://pypi.org/simple/h5py/) (requires-python:>=3.6). Command errored out with exit status 1: /Users/user/projects/ucloud/federated/venv/bin/python /Users/user/projects/ucloud/federated/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /private/var/folders/14/3fhr7hps0yvfd43qp60rbw480000gn/T/pip-build-env-9ws6euzt/normal --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- 'numpy==1.12; python_version == "3.6"' pkgconfig 'numpy==1.19.3; python_version >= "3.9"' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version == "3.7"' 'numpy==1.17.5; python_version == "3.8"' 'Cython>=0.29.14; python_version >= "3.8"' 'Cython>=0.29; python_version < "3.8"' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Cannot install tensorflow-federated==0.1.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.1, tensorflow-federated==0.11.0, tensorflow-federated==0.12.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.1, tensorflow-federated==0.14.0, tensorflow-federated==0.15.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.1, tensorflow-federated==0.17.0, tensorflow-federated==0.18.0, tensorflow-federated==0.2.0, tensorflow-federated==0.3.0, tensorflow-federated==0.4.0, tensorflow-federated==0.5.0, tensorflow-federated==0.6.0, tensorflow-federated==0.7.0 and tensorflow-federated==0.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflow-federated 0.18.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.4.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.17.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.11.1
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.1 depends on tensorflow~=2.2.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.2.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.15.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.2.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.14.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.2.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.1 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.12.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.7.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.11.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.0.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.1 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.9.0 depends on tfa-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.7.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.6.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.5.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.4.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.3.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.2.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow>=1.13.0rc2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

I guess it happened because some required packages is not ready to satisfy the Apple Silicon M1 with the ARM architecture? Am I right?

Is there any solution to install Tensorflow Federated in a macOS with Apple Silicon M1 now?

---

Edited on Mar 20, 2021:

Thanks for the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705900/can-tensorflow-federated-be-installed-on-apple-silicon-m1#comment117928552_66705900) from the user [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd).

The problem of numpy is solved by following [this commend](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17807#issuecomment-731014921).

But the dependency conflict is still here.

```
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
Collecting h5py
  Using cached h5py-3.2.1.tar.gz (368 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Installing backend dependencies ... |^[[-^[[done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... done
ERROR: Cannot install tensorflow-federated==0.1.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.0, tensorflow-federated==0.10.1, tensorflow-federated==0.11.0, tensorflow-federated==0.12.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.0, tensorflow-federated==0.13.1, tensorflow-federated==0.14.0, tensorflow-federated==0.15.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.0, tensorflow-federated==0.16.1, tensorflow-federated==0.17.0, tensorflow-federated==0.18.0, tensorflow-federated==0.2.0, tensorflow-federated==0.3.0, tensorflow-federated==0.4.0, tensorflow-federated==0.5.0, tensorflow-federated==0.6.0, tensorflow-federated==0.7.0 and tensorflow-federated==0.9.0 because these package versions have conflicting dependencies.

The conflict is caused by:
    tensorflow-federated 0.18.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.4.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.17.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.3.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.1 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.16.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.15.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.10.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.14.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.9.1
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.1 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.13.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.12.0 depends on tensorflow~=2.1.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.11.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.1 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.10.0 depends on tensorflow-addons~=0.6.0
    tensorflow-federated 0.9.0 depends on tfa-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.7.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.6.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.5.0 depends on tf-nightly
    tensorflow-federated 0.4.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.3.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.2.0 depends on tensorflow~=1.13
    tensorflow-federated 0.1.0 depends on tensorflow>=1.13.0rc2

To fix this you could try to:
1. loosen the range of package versions you've specified
2. remove package versions to allow pip attempt to solve the dependency conflict

ERROR: ResolutionImpossible: for help visit https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#fixing-conflicting-dependencies
```

Comment: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/17807

Comment: Thanks! The problem on building numpy is solved by following [phd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7976758/phd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66705900/can-tensorflow-federated-be-installed-on-apple-silicon-m1#comment117928552_66705900)!

Comment: I also post an [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/issues/1254) on GitHub for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to install `tensorflow-federated==0.24` on Python 3.9.13. Here are the steps:

- `conda install tensorflow`
- `pip install tensorflow-metal`  (for M1 GPU support)
- `conda install scipy=1.5.3`
- to solve the problem with `grpcio` enter the following flags in the current terminal

```
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_OPENSSL=1
export GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1
```

- `pip install tensorflow-federated` (should build everything properly, it should install the version 0.24.0, not 0.1.0)
- use conda to update JAX: `conda install jax --force-reinstall`

Comment: Hey, friend. I have given up using TFF on M1, so I cannot verify your solution. But Thanks a lot for your solution.
Anyone verifying this solution please upvote it, thanks!